# How can variables be set to NULL under the strict pragma?

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
my $var = NULL;
```

will raise an error of `Bareword "NULL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There's no NULL in Perl. However, variables can be [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html)ined, which means that they have no value set.
Here're some examples of how you can get an undefined variable in Perl:

```
my $var;       # variables are undefined by default
undef $var;    # undef() undefines the value of a variable
$var = undef;  # same, using an alternative syntax
```

To check for definedness of a variable, use [`defined()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html), i.e.

```
print "\$var is undefined\n" unless defined $var;
```

Comment: +1. and powerboy, be careful when checking whether something is defined. it's "if( defined $var )" NOT "if( not undef $var )". the latter will undefine $var.